# WinRT MediaElement hangs after playing about 60 videos

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm making an application which plays lots of videos in a row. However it seems like whenever I hit 60 videos (sometimes less, sometimes a bit more) my app hangs. I made a small sample app which also does this so to me it seems like the problem is within MediaElement control or somewhere deeper.

Here is the code for sample app:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <MediaElement x:Name="player" AutoPlay="False" MediaOpened="player_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="player_MediaEnded" Volume="0.01" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtDebug" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="40" FontSize="20" Text="Videos played: 0" Foreground="Yellow" />
        <Button Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="40,100,0,0" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace App2
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        await SetPlayerVideo();
    }

    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SetPlayerVideo()
    {
        // get next video file, open it and set it to MediaElement.
        var nextVideo = await this.SelectNextVideo();
        var videoStream = await nextVideo.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        this.player.SetSource(videoStream, "");
    }

    private void player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // When MediaElement.SetSource finishes, begin play.
        MediaElement elem = sender as MediaElement;
        elem.Play();
    }

    private async void player_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update debug text and start next video when one ends.
        this.txtDebug.Text = string.Format("Videos played: {0}", this.videoIndex);
        await SetPlayerVideo();
    }

    private int videoIndex = 0; // Index used to loop through files in temp folder in case there are multiple video files

    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> SelectNextVideo()
    {
        var files = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        var file = files.ElementAt(this.videoIndex % files.Count);
        videoIndex++;
        return file;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDebug.Text = "button click";
    }
}
}
```

To test put one wmv file into TempState folder. Preferably short video as it requires to run tens of times to reproduce issue. I used a countdown clip from this site: http://www.movietools.info/video-background-loops/countdown-loops.html

I downloaded some applications from Windows Store with playlist feature, added about 100x 10 second clips and hit play. They all had the same problem, hanged after about 60 videos were played.

Any suggestions or ideas how to get around the issue? I have also tried creating new MediaElement each time video ends but it didn't help.

Next I'll probably research VLC player a bit since they don't seem to use default MediaElement for playing videos. But I haven't really checked if their license allows the use of their dlls in my app or if I can even compile the sources.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be related to AMD graphics card and seems to be fixed after updating drivers to latest version.